# Multiple DbSet<> for same entity but with different filters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

To make life easier for some of our developers, I want to create two `DbSet<>` for one database entity/table. Here's an example:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> DeletedUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> ActiveUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //for ActiveUsers
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.Deleted == null);

        //for DeletedUsers
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.Deleted != null);
    }
}
```

How can I make my two DbSet<> differentiate between these two? I want to be able to say `dbContext.DeletedUsers.Where(x => x.Id == .....)` instead of having to say `dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Deleted != null && x.Id == ......)` all the same, as people might not remember that they're dealing with deleted users (or counterwise).

Comment: how about using EF Core's global filter? as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: Id postulate, even if you could do this you would create more issues than you solve in the long term

Comment: @TheGeneral Most likely, yep.

Comment: Why use two different DbSets instead of adding two properties that return the `IQueryable` you want, eg `Users.Where(...)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use a DbSet for that since it's the same Entity, just expose an IQueryable property, eg

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<User> ActiveUsers => Users.Where(e => e.Deleted == null);

    public IQueryable<User> DeletedUsers => Users.Where(e => e.Deleted != null);

}
```

And you also can omit the `Users` property if you like, and configure `User` as an entity on OnModelCreating, then accessing all users only through `DbContext.Set<User>()` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that since EF has no way to distinguish between the two things. You could apply the query filter to only show active users and if deleted users are really needed, then the user can call `IgnoreQueryFilters()`, for example:

```
var allusers = context
    .Set<User>()
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you coud use SQL views. For example, something like this (untested code off the top of my head):

Create a view for `ActiveUsers`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW ActiveUsers
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Deleted IS NULL -- Obviously don't use SELECT *...
```

Add a new class for active users:

```
public class ActiveUser
{
    // all the properties
}
```

And configure your DbContext:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<ActiveUser>()
    .ToView("ActiveUsers")
    .HasKey(t => t.Id);
```

Then do the same for `DeletedUsers`.

Comment: Okay yep, I thought it wasn't possible as well. Using a View would probably be a good idea then. Quite annoying that I would have to have identical code and classes around the code, as I would have to remember to change them if my design ever changes. Hm. I'll have to rethink this, I guess. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively I could add a `public bool IsDeleted => Deleted != null` property, but that's also a bit meh.

Comment: You could create a base class with the properties and inherit from it to save duplication there. Another potential benefit of using views is that SQL Server can get a slight performance boost

Comment: That's true. A few possibilities here. As the data isn't critical (the deleted is just an example), I'll probably just create a non-mapping boolean to the property I need to check on. It won't hurt performance much, if one accidentally forgets to filter on the property